# Please Explain this ECMASCRIPT code and syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain me this code. Also explain this syntax `${name}` (I've already google it, but got nothing much).

```js
function* ask() { 
   const name = yield "What is your name?"; 
   const sport = yield "What is your favorite sport?"; 
   return `${name}'s favorite sport is ${sport}`; 
}  
const it = ask(); 
console.log(it.next()); 
console.log(it.next('Ethan'));  
console.log(it.next('Cricket'));
```

Comment: here is the explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: And the template literal ( `${name}` ) explanation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

1. The function you are declaring is a generator. You can find more about generators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A
2. `${name}` This is a way to add a variable's value to the string. This is called literals. You can find out more about literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Let me know if you are still confused.